# How can I use service configuration in Azure from application level?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, app-config

I have some cloud service implemented in C#. Whole solution consists of Service Project with some settings, separate projects for multiple roles + one separate project with main logic of the application. Now, I need to distinguish application url depending on environment it is run on. I know (suspect might be better choice of words) I can modify `ServiceConfiguration.<Cloud|Local>.cscfg` file by adding `<Setting name="domain" value="example.com" />`

Now, the question I'd like to ask is: how can access this configuration value from source code?

Comment: Are you asking about how you can read these configuration setting through your code? Normal way of reading this is: `RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configurationSettingsKey)`.

Comment: Yes I am. But is it possible to get configuration setting that is configured for a one project (role or cloud service) from the different project which holds main app logic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is certainly possible. So if you have a cloud project `A` and that has a setting `<Setting name="domain" value="exampleA.com" />` and then you have cloud project `B` that has a setting `<Setting name="domain" value="exampleB.com" />` and then you have main project which is used in both cloud projects A and B.

When you run project A and read the setting `domain` from your main project you will get `exampleA.com` and when you run project B and read the same setting, you will get `exampleB.com`.

Comment: Thanks. However though I'd like to set a variable in the Cloud app where I have files local and cloud and access to those config from all projects to those values depending on the running env - compute emulator or actual azure.

Comment: Aah I see ... in this case your code would be somewhat complicated. One possibility is to have separate settings (by name) for emulator and cloud. Other possibility is to always different values in `ServiceConfiguration.local.cscfg' and `ServiceConfiguration.cloud.cscfg`.

Answer (score 0):

I added to the ServiceConfigurationCloud.cscfg and the ServiceConfigurationLocal.cscfg

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
<Setting name="DataBaseConnectionString" value="Data Source=MYNAME.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD"/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

Then I added to the ServiceDefinition.csdef file.

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
  <Setting name="DataBaseConnectionString"/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

Within the code I was able to read from the file by using

```
string DBCO = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DataBaseConnectionString");
```